# Problem with missing tabs when transposing data

Tags: command-line

I am having issues when transposing and printing the contents of ~2000 txt files. Some of the values are missing a tab or space after them and so they get joined.

Here is an example - say I have the following file1.txt file:

```
6
5
1764
473
3790
421
2296
1379
818
706
2733
1160
1277
189
1453
4569
1241
7040
950
2842
171
1176
0
0
8
```

I have ~2000 files similar to this. I want to put them into rows with the file name in column 1:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    printf "%s\t" "$f"   # print filename
    awk '{print $1}' "$f" | paste -s  
done
```

However I get the following output - here, there numbers 1277 and 189 are joined / missing a tab:

```
file1.txt   6   5   1764    473 3790    421 2296    1379    818 706 2733    1160    1277189 1453    4569    1241    7040    950 2842    171 1176    0   0   8
```

Would be great to know where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `awk` command. You could simplify with `paste -s "$f"`. If that doesn' work please update your question with the exact error you're having.

Comment: Assuming your files don't contain any empty lines, you could read each one as a single record and output them as lines using the field separator of your choice directly in awk e.g. `awk -vRS= -vOFS='\t' '{$1 = FILENAME OFS $1} 1' *.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks but that also gives the same problem...

Comment: Works fine for me - perhaps there's something funny in your input data? try examining it with `cat -A`

Comment: Do you redirect the output to a file, or just let it appear in the terminal emulator? In the latter case it's not expected to work as you'd think. TABs are control (non-printable) characters in terminal emulators to jump to the next tab stop (or the last position) within a line. If the cursor is already at the last position, a tab doesn't do anything (it's swallowed).

Comment: @egmont ah thanks! How do I print it to a txt file output? Sorry, fairly new to this...

Comment: `> file` (see "REDIRECTION" in bash's manual).